# org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28001: the password has expired )

Tags: oracle

I have an app that is using Oracle 11g as the db, and we had neglected to set the password expiration to never and the app itself then failed when the original password expired.  We corrected that, and reset the password back to the original, and for some reason, while most of the functionality is working properly, part is not (throws the error in title).  Below is the output from the log file. I have tried rebooting the server etc, but still get the same issue.  Any thought?

Thanks!!!

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:23 | INFO: webClient: Request attributes: [service=tsapprovals][tb=managedresources][oid=][action=splitpanecontroller][orderBy=][sortBy=] from Host[108.28.145.157]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:23 | AbandonedObjectPool is used (org.apache.commons.dbcp.AbandonedObjectPool@51f1e39b)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:23 |    LogAbandoned: true
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:23 |    RemoveAbandoned: true
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:23 |    RemoveAbandonedTimeout: 300
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28001: the password has expired
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1225)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.util.DBConnectionFactory.getPooledConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:459)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.util.DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:242)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.util.DBConnectionFactory.getConnection(DBConnectionFactory.java:221)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.util.DBConnectionFactory.<init>(DBConnectionFactory.java:157)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.util.DBConnectionFactory.getInstance(DBConnectionFactory.java:208)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.report.db.CrossPointDBUtility.<init>(CrossPointDBUtility.java:45)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.report.queries.DBQuery.initialize(DBQuery.java:64)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.report.queries.approval.PendingApprovalsQuery.initialize(PendingApprovalsQuery.java:34)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.command.splitpane.services.PendingApprovals.execute(PendingApprovals.java:65)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.command.splitpane.SplitPaneCommand.displayControllerPane(SplitPaneCommand.java:120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.command.splitpane.SplitPaneCommand.execute(SplitPaneCommand.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.servlet.CommandProcessor.processAction(CommandProcessor.java:1587)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.servlet.CommandProcessor.process(CommandProcessor.java:1156)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.servlet.Controller.handleRequest(Controller.java:210)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.velocity.servlet.VelocityServlet.doRequest(VelocityServlet.java:358)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at isc.thinclient.web.servlet.Controller.doRequest(Controller.java:838)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.velocity.servlet.VelocityServlet.doGet(VelocityServlet.java:317)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:874)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28001: the password has expired
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:283)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:278)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.receiveOauth(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:791)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:362)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:294)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1247)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1221)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 |   ... 34 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | loggedInUSer: System Administrator Thu Nov 01 18:13:24 UTC 2012
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2012/11/01 13:13:24 | isc.thinclient.api.ThinAPIException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28001: the password has expired
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the password for your user profile has been expired, please try to execute the below query which can resolve this issue - for `username` and `password` use your values.

```
ALTER USER username IDENTIFIED BY password;
```